# Grouping all results in infinite scroll

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, group-by

I have a latest commented on post feature.. So when a post is commented on it jumps to the top. 
I would like to know how it is possible to group all posts by their streamitem_id.in the initial call but in every call after that. so if a post matched in the 4th scroll with one in the second scroll i would like it not to show because I'd prefer it to be grouped together

I tried the GROUP by method in the below query and it just grouped items in every new scroll because its making a new call.

```
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM streamdata m
    JOIN streamdata_comments t1 
    WHERE";
    if ($last_id!==0) {
    $query .= " t1.comment_id < $last_id AND";
    }
    $query .= " t1.comment_streamitem=m.streamitem_id
    GROUP BY m.streamitem_id
    ORDER BY t1.comment_id DESC LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('Error: ' . 
    mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

UPDATE
I have tried the below and getting closer to what I need. its grouping the items..but now its throwing in a random post that shouldn't even be in there.
        `$query = "
        SELECT *
        FROM streamdata_comments t1 
        JOIN streamdata m
        ON";
        if ($last_id!==0) {
        $query .= " t1.comment_id < $last_id GROUP BY t1.comment_streamitem 
        AND";
        }
        $query .= "
        m.streamitem_id=t1.comment_streamitem
        AND t1.comment_poster=34 AND comment_type_id=1
        ORDER BY t1.comment_id DESC LIMIT 2";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('Error: ' . 
        mysqli_error($mysqli));`

Comment: Not including the ON for the join, transforms the join into a `cross join`

Comment: ON m.streamitem_id = t1.comment_streamitem
WHERE t1.comment_id < $last_id

Comment: Also, if you want to ignore certain post_ids, then I would suggest that you send them as part of the request

Comment: are you showing the posts alone or the comments as well?

Answer (score 0):

If ID "2342" is the ID for the third result and "2222" is the ID for the second result, then it sounds like your IDs are not incremented values OR there is a problem with your sort clause. The newest comment should be the highest value. I would make sure your query is returning results with the "t1.comment_id" value in descending order. If the IDs are not in fact incremented values or the sort clause is invalid this line would not be valid.

```
$query .= " t1.comment_id < $last_id AND";
```

If the above doesn't get you any further a couple other things to verify would be that $last_id is in fact the previous ID, so on the second request $last_id should really be '2222' in the current query.

One other possibility I could be wrong on but this line of the JOIN might be in the wrong place, it seems it is part of the WHERE clause. Perhaps moving that up after the JOIN might help:

```
$query .= " t1.comment_streamitem=m.streamitem_id
```

If none of these prevail I would suggest providing more info on the design or perhaps a dump of the query and response.

Comment: @chaduhduh I'm confused by your response. My results are showing correctly. I asked about grouping the same posts with the same id's, So if a commented on post of 2345 was in the initial call a fourth commented on post in the fourth row wouldn't show as a fourth result with the same id of 2345 has already shown in the first call.

Comment: so on page load 2345 (last commented post id) 2222 (commented on before 2345) then scroll for the next two results in the table 2342 (is the third commented on item) then 2345 (shows again as this were the fourth commented on item but shouldn't because it should be paired with the initial 2345 post  (first two results) on page load.